# Por que no da la suma de nombresen MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
CREATE Table apellidos_completo (Completo varchar (255))

INSERT INTO apellidos_completo (Completo )values ('alvarez')

UPDATE apellidos_completo set Completo =  'Rodriguez' + Completo
```

Hago SELECT

```
SELECT *
FROM apellidos_completo
```

el resultado deberia ser

```
'Rodriguez Alvarez'
```

Sin embargo el resultado obtenido es:

```
(0) osea CERO
```

NOTA:si lo hagoen SQL server si me funciona, Bien pero en MySQL no me sale.

Comment: deseas unir esas 2 cadenas de texto?

Comment: si no recuerdo como se hace u.u

Comment: ¿Es MySQL o SQL Server? No comprendo por qué le pusiste las dos etiquetas...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La unión, no la suma; se hace por medio de la función `CONCAT()`, que me ayuda a concatenar o unir varios valores, guíate por este ejemplo

```
SET @varUno = 'Pack';
SET @varDos = ' nombre';


MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT CONCAT(@varUno, @varDos) AS Mensaje;
+-------------+
| Mensaje     |
+-------------+
| Pack nombre |
+-------------+
```

> Dicha función, necesita por dentro y separados por comas los valores
>   que deseas unir, por último con un alias le damos un nombre temporal a
>   la tabla que me ha de mostrar los resultados

Dentro de tu código te retorna 0 por que esta tomando o tratando de tomar los valores como aquellos que puede sumar por que usas el signo +, al no ser de tipo numérico retorna 0

En todo caso lo que buscas obtener no es la suma de las cadenas de texto sino la concatenación de las mismas que es muy distinto